# Deriving a valid inequality

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, valid-inequalities, cuts

Given a set of facilities $I$ and days $J$, each facility $i \in I$ has a capacity of $C_i$, and a set of days $J$ where in each day $j \in J$ there's a total demand of $q_j$ that can be satisfied by one or more facilities.

To satisfy the daily demand facilities are opened. The number of opened facilities of type $i$ should be equivalent on all days, hence the global cost of opening one facility of type $i$ is $h_{i}^{g} = |J|h_{i} $.  In addition, among the opened facilities, in each day $j$ a number of them can be canceled recovering the cost of opening one facility ($h_i$) and subject to a penalty ($h^{'}_i$) if the total number of canceled ones exceeds a certain threshold $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1.0$ (e.g percentage) of the total number of opened facilities of type $i$. Thus we have $h^{'}_i <  h_i < h_{i}^{g}$.

The problem is to find the number of facilities of type $i$ to be opened in all days and the one to be canceled in each day $j$ while minimizing the total cost of opened, cancelled and penalized facilities.

Let the following integer variables be:
$y_i$ = Total number of opened facilities
$x_{ij}$ = number of canceled facilities of type $i$ in day $j$
$w_i$ = number of penalized facilities among the canceled ones
$z_{ij}$ = actual number of facilities of type $i$ used in day $j$ ($z_{ij} = y_i - x_{ij}, \forall i,j)$
$d_{ij}$ = amount sent from facility $i$ to satisfy the demand in day $j$.

The objective function minimizes: $\sum_{i\in I} h_{i}^{g} y_i + \sum_{i\in I} h^{'}_i w_i - \sum_{i\in I,j\in J} h_i x_{ij}$.

In addition we have the following constraints:
(1) $\sum_{i} d_{ij} = q_{j}, \forall j$ : demand satisfaction
(2) $d_{ij} \leq C_i z_{ij}, \forall i,j$: capacity constraints
(3) $z_{ij} = y_i - x_{ij}, \forall i,j$: actual number of used facilities $i$ in day $j$
(4) $x_{ij} \leq y_i,\forall i,j$: no cancellation if facility is not opened
(5) $\sum_{j~\in{J}} x_{ij} - \beta y_{i} \leq w_{i} , \forall i$: penalize only if total cancellation exceeds $\alpha$ percentage of total number of y_{i}. Concretely $\beta = \alpha \times |{J}|$, $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1.0$. For example $\beta = 0.2$ where $\alpha = 10\%$ and $|{J}| =2$. This constraint states that if:

1. $\sum_{j~\in~{J}} x_{ij} - \beta y_{i} \leq 0 \rightarrow w_{i} =0, \forall i~\in~{I} $
2. $\sum_{j~\in~{J}} x_{ij} - \beta y_{i} > 0 \rightarrow w_{i} \geq \sum_{j~\in~{J}} x_{ij} - \beta y_{i}, \forall i~\in~{I} $

Now imagine $|I| = 2$ such that $C_0 = 50$ and $C_1 = 60$, $h_0 = 500$, $h_1 = 550$, $h^{'}_{0} =400 $, $h^{'}_{1} =440$. $|J| = 2$, $q_0 = 75$, $q_1 = 110$ and $\beta = 0.2$.

Given these parameters, the optimal solution of the LP relaxation is $y_1 = 1.833333$, $x_{10} = 0.5833333$, $w_1 = 0.216667$, $d_{10} = 75$, $d_{11} = 110$.

It's not difficult to find this given that if  $y_1 = 1.833333$ then:
in day 0: $C_1 \times y_1 = 60 \times 1.83333 = 110 - 75 = 35 => 35/60 =0.583333$ which equals the cancellation
in day 1: $C_1 \times y_1 = 60 \times 1.83333 = 110 - 110 = 0$

then for constraint (5) : $0.58333 - 0.366666 \leq 0.2166667$

I am looking for a way to derive valid inequalities to cutoff this fractional solution (variables are integer) or to strengthen the formulation given the LP relaxation? or what is the right literature to look at to derive such cuts ? I am looking for network design problems with capacity expansion or elimination.
Thank you.

Comment: I suppose that you have a cost on your $w_i$ variables? Otherwise, your constraint does not satisfy your implication in 1.

Comment: Also, do you have any relation between the $y$ and the $w$ variables? I ask, as this looks like some kind of facility location problem, where you can expand the capacity at a cost. In such cases, you normally have $y_i=0\Rightarrow w_i=0$ saying no expansion of a non-existing facility.

Comment: The objective function minimizes the total cost on variables : $\min_{x,y,w} \sum_{i}$ ($h_i y_i $ + $\bar{h_i} w_i$)  - $\sum_{i,j} h_i x_{ij}$, where $\bar{h_i}$ <$h_i$ so $\bar{h_i}$ can be seen as a penalty if the total number of variable $x_{ij}$ exceeds a certain threshold of the total number of variable $y_i$.  Yes if $y_i = 0 \Rightarrow w_i =0$ but this is ensured  if $ \sum_{i,j} x_{ij} - \beta y_i \leq 0$.

Comment: @CHE, is the problem still relevant?

Comment: @A.Omidi yes any help is much appreciated. I've tried a few things but didn't get me nowhere.

Comment: @CHE, as you have some indicator constraints would you try using this ability, indicator constraints, that exists in many of the modern solvers? I mean, instead of translating these constraints by yourself, let the solver do this and then compare what you want? (As far as I know, these kinds of constraints somehow can be translated into the BigM form internally. It causes the solver mechanism can deal with those more effectively in the presence of valid cuts.)

Comment: @CHE, maybe more details about the model would be helpful ..., such as the objective function.

Comment: @A.Omidi I was hoping to add derive some VI to improve the LB since the gap progresses very slowly (I have no problem in finding an integer solution). It's just to converge faster for proven optimality.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade I edited my question in this regard.

Comment: @CHE, is there any case in which an empty solution (zero-valued solution) wouldn't be the optimal? Since that, assigning a day to a facility (x_ij >= 1), updates the y_i, and thus, the term, at the objective function, h_i y_i - h''_i sum_j x_ij, always will be positive.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade an optimal solution never has an empty solution. Let $q_{ij}$=demand on day $j$ that can be satisfied by facility $i$ (can be more than one). $y_{i}$= number of opened facilities (same on all days), $x_{ij}$= number of canceled facilities on day $j$ of type $i$. Yes it's always positive because demand should be satisfied ($y_i$ >0 for at least one $i$). But if we choose the wrong facilities $x_{ij}$ increases and thus the penalization (we only penalize if $\forall i,\sum_{j}x_{ij} > \alpha |J| y_i$  (e.g. $\alpha$=20%) ). if needed I can provide a small example.

Comment: @CHE, could you please update the model to contain the constraint with q_ij?

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade sure it's done.

Comment: @CHE why do your $z$-variables have two indices (both $i$ and $j$)? From the description, they are defined as "actual number of facilities used in day $j$". Nothing in the definition relates to $i$. Should it instead be "actual number of facilities *of type $i$* used in day $j$?

Comment: @Sune Yes you are right, it should be the actual number of facility of type $i$ used in day $j$. I will edit it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @CHE, what does constraint (4) mean?

Comment: @A.Omidi this constraint states that we cannot close a facility of type $i$ on day $j$ if no facility of this type is opened ($y_i =0$). Otherwise, from the opened facility of type $i$ we can close  a maximum of $y_i$ facility on day $j$. $y_i$ should be the same in all days, so for example we open 2 facilities every day but on day 3 we have to close facilities because of decrease in demand, and obviously we can't close more than 2 facilities.

Comment: @CHE, is the constraints (3) the only place that the variable $z_{ij}$ is used? If so, it seems the variable z just can be as a parameter. Also, the constraints (3) and (4) have the very same structure. Do you try to remove the (3) and solve the model? Also, is it possible to write the (2) as an aggregate form?

Comment: @A.Omidi It's also used in constraints (2):  the total amount that can be sent from facility type $i$ in day $j$ is $\leq$ than the total available capacity :$C_i \times$ (opened facility $y_i$ - closed facility $i$ in $j$ ($x_{ij}$), which is given by variable $z_{ij}$.  Variable $z_{ij}$ gives the relation between $y_i$ and $x_{ij}$. If constraint (3) is removed, the objective function = 0 (no relation between $y$ and $x$) and whatever facility will be used to satisfy constraints (1) and (2). In our example: $z_{00} = 2$ and $z_{01} = 3$.

Comment: @CHE, Ah, that's right. I didn't see that.